# update all sensors with one code troubles

Tags: timer, sensors, auto-update

My problem lies in the code in which i cannot seem to define code or remove atribute errors.
in this code block you will find the which im trying to complete:

```
class MainFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.updater = updater()
        self.MainTemp_meter1 = tk.StringVar()
        # Code for temperature gauges...
        temp_reading_top = sensors.sensor.read_temperature()
        #temp_reading_bottom = sensors.sensor.read_temperature()

        # Code for humidity gauges...
        #humid_reading_top = sensors.read_humidity()
        #humid_reading_bottom = sensors.read_humidity()

        date = dt.datetime.now()
        # create label to display
        self.label_timedate = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text=f"{date:%A, %B %d, %Y, %H:%M}")
        self.label_timedate.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        # add widgets onto the frame, for example:
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Status")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

        self.MainTemp_meter1 = Meter(self, radius=200, start=0, end=70, border_width=0, fg="#242424", bg="#242424",
               text_color="white", start_angle=270, end_angle=-270,
               text_font="DS-Digital 12", scale_color="white", needle_color="red", text=" \N{DEGREE SIGN}C")
        self.MainTemp_meter1.set_mark(50, 70) # set red marking from 140 to 160
        self.MainTemp_meter1.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=5)
        self.MainTemp_meter1.set(temp_reading_top)

        self.label3 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Temperature")
        self.label3.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)

        #self.meter2 = Meter(self, radius=200, start=0, end=70, border_width=0, fg="#242424", bg="#242424",
               #text_color="white", start_angle=270, end_angle=-270,
               #text_font="DS-Digital 12", scale_color="white", needle_color="red", text=" \N{DEGREE SIGN}C")
        #self.meter2.set_mark(50, 70) # set red marking from 140 to 160
        #self.meter2.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=5)
        #self.meter2.set(temp_reading_bottom)
        
        self.label_t1 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Timer 1: ")
        self.label_t1.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=10)

        self.progressbar_t1 = ctk.CTkProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar_t1.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")

        self.label_t2 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Timer 2: ")
        self.label_t2.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=10)

        self.progressbar_t2 = ctk.CTkProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar_t2.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")

        self.label_t3 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Timer 3: ")
        self.label_t3.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=10)

        self.progressbar_t3 = ctk.CTkProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar_t3.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        
        if relays.door_close:
            self.label2 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="UV-Oven active")
            self.label2.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20)
            self.img_sun = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("sun.png"),
                                  dark_image=Image.open("sun.png"),
                                  size=(150, 150))
            self.label_sun = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="", image=self.img_sun)
            self.label_sun.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        else:
            self.label4 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="UV-Oven deactivated")
            self.label4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20)
            
            
        if temp_reading_top > 60:
            self.label2 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="warning: temperature exceeded")
            self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)
            self.img_cross = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("cross.png"),
                                  dark_image=Image.open("cross.png"),
                                  size=(150, 150))
            self.label_cross = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="", image=self.img_cross)
            self.label_cross.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")

            
        updater.update_readings(self)
```

and in this code you will find my updater for which ill be using for the time being.

```
class updater:
    #def __init__(self, master=None):
        #super().__init__()
        #self.master = master
        #self.main_frame = main_frame
        #self.diag_frame = diag_frame
        #self.timer_frame = timer_frame
    def update_readings(self):
            try:
                while True:
                    # Update temperature reading 
                    temp_reading_top = sensors.sensor.read_temperature()
                    humid_reading_top = sensors.sensor.read_humidity()
                    sensors.Temperature_Sensor.read_temperature 
                    sensors.Temperature_Sensor.read_humidity
                    #DiagFrame.humid_meter1.set(humid_reading_top)

                    # Update current date and time
                    date = dt.datetime.now()
                    #MainFrame.label_timedate.configure(text=f"{date:%A, %B %d, %Y, %H:%M}")

                    # Update timer label 
                    #timer_reading = TimerFrame.timer10.read_current()
                    #formatted_time = timers.Timer.format_time(timer_reading)  # Call format_time from timers.Timer
                    #TimerFrame.time_var.set(formatted_time)
                    timers.Timer.read_current

                    print('updated')

                    # Update the GUI
                    #MainFrame.update_idletasks(self)
                    #DiagFrame.update_idletasks(self)
                    #TimerFrame.update_idletasks(self)

                    # Delay for a certain period (e.g., 1 second)
                    time.sleep(0.2)

                    self.update_readings

                    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_readings)
                    update_thread.daemon = True
                    update_thread.start()

            except Exception as e:
                    print("Update error:", str(e))
```

i tried a lot of things in which i can't even count those on 2 hands. im expecting to let this code work before the end of the week.

ill show my main error code here
`'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'update_readings'`